# Using Google analytics to show online users?

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering whether it is possible to use Google Analytics stats to extract number of online users, something like whos.amung.us? If not, what alternative outsourced solutions are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics can't do this. Something like [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/) should work for you, though.

There are also scripts out there that can do this for you. There's one [here](http://www.roscripts.com/How_many_visitors_online_PHP_script-108.html) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?700163-How-to-Count-Number-of-Visitors-Viewing-My-Site).